# Installation of numpy in PyCharm on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pycharm

I keep getting errors when I try to install numpy in Pycharm (Windows)

This is the error I get 
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Is there an easier way to use SciPy/Numpy on Windows, by using a different IDE?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking "Is there a better python IDE?" or "how do I get rid if this error?"

Comment: Sounds like she's trying to use SciPy on Windows, and having trouble installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/).

It's a single installation that includes SciPy and NumPy. Then you should be able to use those modules inside PyCharm.